# PHP SDK MS Graph result count

Tags: php, microsoft-graph-api

Issue: Resultset returned only has 200 results.

```
 $driveItems = $response->getResponseAsObject(\Microsoft\Graph\Model\DriveItem::class);
```

This request returns a list of 200 directories but there are ~300+ in the base directory.
I cannot seem to locate the documentation which covers the volume of results returned. Only a reference to pageSize()

```
$docGrabber = $graph->createCollectionRequest("GET", "/me/drive/root/children")
                ->setReturnType(Model\DriveItem::class)
                ->setPageSize(2);
```

There is also a reference to

> Some queries against Microsoft Graph return multiple pages of data either due to server-side paging or due to the use of the $top query

Where is the $top query set? how does this affect the total record count?

What is the best way to get results for more than 200 records?

UPDATE: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-list-children?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=php

> Note: If a collection exceeds the default page size (200 items), the @odata.nextLink property is returned in the response to indicate more items are available and provide the request URL for the next page of items.

Also: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/query-parameters?tabs=http

> $top  Sets the page size of results.

Answer (score 0):

$top URL query parameter resolved the issue.

```
$endpoint = $this->rootDir.'/children?top=xxxx
```

Note that this is using Sharepoint (SITES) endpoints

```
'site' => '/sites/{orgname}.sharepoint.com,061c4-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx -63549',
'list' => '/lists/1b88-xxxxxxxxx-4f0f', 
'drive' => '/drive/items/01NWM__________________U34D',
```

Simple resolution to at URL QUERY parameter to endpoint request.